# Nginx: How to Send to Client Result of a Python Script?

Tags: python, nginx, system-calls, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a simple python script: the generates an `x-icon` from a hex colour given to it, then it returns a valid byte-stream (`BytesIO`).

I want to get something like this (please, do not laugh, I'm using Nginx for about two days):

```
location ~^/icons/(?<colour>[a-fA-F0-9]{6})\.ico$ {
    send 200 (./favicon.py colour); # System call to `favicon.py` with `colour` argument.
}
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: maybe [this](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/09/18/how-to-execute-cgi-scripts-using-fcgiwrap/) will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following config should do the work:

```
location ~^/icons/(?<colour>[a-fA-F0-9]{6})\.ico$ {
    content_by_lua '
        local command = "./favicon.py colour"
        local handle = io.popen(command)
        local content = handle:read("*a")
        handle:close()
        ngx.print(content)
    ';
}
```

Basically it uses Lua for executing and providing the content

NOTE: your nginx should be compiled with the lua module for this solution to work

Comment: If I set `root` in Nginx as `/some/path`, `./favicon.py` will be expanded to `/some/path/favicon.py`, right?

Comment: Also I'm getting error `missing ) in "^/icons/(?<colour>[a-fA-F0-9]`, but in my config all is correct: `location ~^/icons/(?<colour>[a-fA-F0-9]{6})\.ico$`.

Comment: 1. Not sure, I guess it will use the running directory of the nginx process, but it might be the defined `root` or something else. You can use full path.

2. I just copied the location from you, use the location you need, not the one I wrote